# How to Query One to Many in Linq

Tags: linq-to-entities

--I have a **Table** named **CLASS** with the Following Records in it

```
     (PK)        
    ClassID   |   Name     
    ----------|----------
     1        |    CSE        
     2        |    ECE
```

I have an another **Table** Named **ALLOCATIONS** which has the ForeighnKey **Class_ID** from **CLASS** table

```
   (PK)        (FK)
    ID   |   Class_ID   |   EffectiveFrom  |   Allocation
    -----|--------------|------------------|---------------
     1   |       1      |    10-May-2011   |      A
     2   |       1      |    10-May-2011   |      B
     3   |       1      |    14-June-2011  |      A
    ---------------------------------------|---------------
     4   |       2      |    14-June-2011  |      C   
     5   |       2      |    14-June-2011  |      D
     6   |       2      |    17-June-2011  |      C
```

I have the **CSE** & **ECE** Classes in an **IQueryable[CLASS]** variable, now i need the following  Allocation Table Records based on the Highest **EffectiveFrom** Date like below:

```
   (PK)        (FK)
    ID   |   Class_ID   |   EffectiveFrom  |   Allocation
    -----|--------------|------------------|---------------
     2   |       1      |    10-May-2011   |      B
     3   |       1      |    14-June-2011  |      A
    ---------------------------------------|---------------
     5   |       2      |    14-June-2011  |      D
     6   |       2      |    17-June-2011  |      C
```

How to do it in LINQ (Preferable in LAMBDA Expression), i need the results in **AllocationType** not **AnaymousType**

Thank you!

Regards
Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
from allocation in CurrentClasses.Allocations 
     group allocation by allocation.Class_ID
     into allocationGroups
     from allocationGroup in allocationGroups
     from allocationRow in allocationGroup
     where allocationRow.Date == allocationGroup.Max(x => x.Date)
     select allocationRow;
```

Hope that helps, sorry for the query syntax, but I haven't got much experience with joins in lambda.

Comment: but i need the Record with the Highest EffectiveFrom date! The Given Query will just return records ordered by effective From.  look at the Example!

Comment: so sorry, misread the question. not sure about this version either. give me a minute...

Comment: no worries, will be here for a little while. love linq by the way, so happy to help.

Comment: First of all Thanks for ur Time and Effort!! Here the **allocations** in the Join Comes from the ObjectContext Right?, but my problem is I only have the IQueryable<Class> Variable, i need to get the **allocations** through the realtion in the IQueryable<Class> Variable!

Comment: Uh, I think you'd have to get a reference to the allocations table from somewhere, as the variable holds no information related to the other table. The reference is set in the allocations table via a foreign key, so it is not possible to get to it from just the class table unfortunately.

Comment: would this help **CurrentClasses.SelectMany(cc => cc.Allocations.Select(s => s.EffectiveFrom).Max());**

Comment: if you can do that, then you have a reference to Allocations in CurrentClasses, so you should be able to run the code above. I think the statement you wrote just then, selects only the effective from column, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes u r right....it select only the EffectiveFromColumn....  Ok then.. thank u for ur time.... i'll try some thing else... Thank you Soooo Muchhhhh....

Comment: one more modification, hope this is it now :-)

Comment: Yup .. u've almost given me the Solution.. thank u for ur kind heart... and time and Effort.... thank you Soo much

Comment: u've spent almost 1hr working for someone's problem,.. really appreciate ur effort.. thank u soo much..